# Plotly error for large facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table, plotly

I think I might have found a bug associated with the `ggplotly` function in the `plotly` package.

In the following bit of code, the result works for n = 9 but not n = 10.

Can anybody suggest a work around, or at least a reason for the bug?

```
require(data.table)
require(plotly)
require(ggplot2)

n <- 10
jj <- CJ(week=c(1:n),day=c('Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'),hour=c(0:23))
jj[,day:=factor(day,levels = c('Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'))]
jj[,n:=rnorm(nrow(jj))]
p1 <- ggplot(jj,aes(x=hour,y=n))+geom_line()+facet_grid(week~day)
p1
p1 <- ggplotly(p1)
p1
```

Thanks,

Comment: You can file bugs [here](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/).

Comment: Fyi, instead of `nrow(jj)`, you can just use `.N`.